# Apple Detecting Jailbreak on a NOT jailbroken iPhone

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I recently received a notification that took up the whole screen on my iphone which says that I have breached the Apple terms and conditions for jailbreaking my iphone.

However, I am pretty sure that I haven't done any jail breaking to it and it is a definitely a new piece of hardware since I bought it directly from the telco with the box and wraps.

What could be the reason for this happening and what should I do? It has been working fine for a year or so, till this message pop up recently.

Answer (score 1):

That notification could have come from any app.  Check under your settings which apps you have got that you allow notifications from.  I am not aware of any official method for Apple to send these out, and unless there was some sort of corrective action or advice attached I can't see the point in you receiving it either.  This is almost impossible to provide a real answer to, but my first thoughts are either a prank or compromised notification through one of your existing apps.

If you receive it again, take a screen shot - hold down your home button, then tap the power button - the screen will flash white and the picture will appear in your camera roll.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I haven't been installing any apps since quite sometime ago, at least half a year. But if it's a prank or compromised notification why did it take so long to be activated then? The notification claims that it will be de-activating my cellular network service which I am quite worried about. But I don't think there's any corrective message stated though.

Comment: Definitely sounds like a scam to me.  If you are worried, speak to your phone contract people.  A notification can be sent at any time, so long as it is allowed in your settings.

Comment: so the best thing to do is just to hit the dismiss button and contact the telcos? Or should I just ignore it any do nothing because I will definitely incur a high very roaming fee for calling back to my country.

Comment: Definitely take a screenshot first.  Also, go through your list of allowed notifications in the main settings app, and turn them off for anything that you are not using and do not, that may help pin down which is the guilty party in future, or it may make it go away if you turn it off for the app that was sending it.  If you are currently roaming, then wait till you get home.

Comment: There is no way that your telco can tell what state your phone is in, unless perhaps if you have got it tethered unofficially, in which case they can spot that, although you would almost certainly have needed to either Jailbreak or mess around with your mobile APN settings etc on purpose

Answer (score 1):

If it took the whole screen, then it can't be a push notification like stuffe [suggests](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22120/apple-detecting-jailbreak-on-a-not-jailbroken-iphone/22123#22123).

But it's something your network provider can do. I've seen it on my iPhone, too. It wasn't about jailbreaking, just some (very intrusive) ads. But it was fullscreen and I couldn't do anything before I clicked on it.

It's probably an error from your provider, so you may want to check with them.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but it claims that it will de-activate my cellular service within 48 hours, how true can it be then? do I just have to wait? There's another issue at hand which is I am currently overseas and the iphone is using the sim card from the telco back in my own country, and it is currently on the roaming function, which connects to a provider in the country I am in now. Which provider should I be contacting then?

Comment: Does it only happens on your current network? Or the one in your country, too? Either way, I would contact your main provider (the one which who you have a contract), they're the one having agreements with providers in others countries. They're the most likely to help you solve this issue.

Comment: I haven't receive any thing like that before when I was back in my country. It was only recently that I received it when I am overseas. But the irony is again, I have been overseas for a few months too, and it's only now that I receive it.